# How to Custom Comment History In Admin Dashboard Sales Order?

Tags: magento-1.9

How to Custom Comment History In Page Sales Order And programmatically Comment History In Admin Order ?

[image]

I've added Config.xml,

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>ig/css/main.css</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="order_tab_info">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>ig/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="adminhtml/ig_sales_order_view_history" name="ig_order_history" template="ig/sales/order/view/history.phtml"></block>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

How to add Block history.phtml?

And how the flow controller Post in my module?

Comment: you want to rewrite the comment history block?

Comment: @qaisar-satti Yes, I would like to rewrite and there are additional selection of templates you want to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set your history template

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
      <reference name="order_history">
         <action method="setTemplate"><template>ig/sales/order/view/history.phtml</template></action>
      </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

override controller

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Namespace_Modeulename before="Mage_Adminhtml">
                        Namespace_Modeulename_Adminhtml
                    </Namespace_Modeulename>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

app/code/local/Namespace/Modeulename/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/OrderController.php

```
<?php

 require_once "Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php";

 class Namespace/Modeulename/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController {

  public function addCommentAction()
   {
     die("H");
    }
}
```

Comment: how the controller of this module comment ?

Comment: updated the code but not tested..

Comment: Where event email template Comment?

Comment: this code do that `$order->sendOrderUpdateEmail($notify, $comment);`

Comment: What if I want to move the sales invoice history, to the sales order history ?

Comment: sorry don't get you. you want to add sales invoice history?

Comment: I want to add Comment temlate Email to the customer by email in the settings of the Configuration Sales Email

Comment: i think you can do it from `transactional email` from admin panel

Comment: How to add 2 Form  coment in Sales Order ?  now there is only one comment,

Comment: you want to add two text areas so user can add two comment at once?

Comment: Yes, with a different template and submit button is also 2, how do I solve it?

Comment: add different form for both that is how you can do that.